# MySQL Time Ranges Grouped By DAYNAME

Tags: mysql

I need assistance with working out the summary of values grouped by custom time ranges (no intervals) and then grouped by days. For example:

```
Monday    (00:00-07:00, 07:00-11:00, 11:00-13:00, 13:00-19:00 and 19:00-00:00)
Tuesday   (00:00-07:00, 07:00-11:00, 11:00-13:00, 13:00-19:00 and 19:00-00:00)
Wednesday (00:00-07:00 ...
```

I know to group by week day would be:

```
select count(values), DAYNAME(date) as Day from data group by Day;
```

And doing a normal non-time range as follow:

```
select  sum(case when clients between 0 and 30 then 1 end) as '0-30'
,sum(case when clients between 30 and 120 then 1 end) as '30-120'
,sum(case when clients between 120 and 300 then 1 end) as '120-300'
,sum(case when clients between 300 and 900 then 1 end) as '300-900'
,sum(case when clients between 900 and 1800 then 1 end) as '900-1800'
,sum(case when clients between 1800 and 3600 then 1 end) as '1800-3600'
,sum(case when clients between 3600 and 14400 then 1 end) as '3600-14400'
,sum(case when clients >= 14400 then 1 end) as '14400+'
    from data;
```

But how to do it with a time range and weekdays?

Comment: Of course, your example code would start to return baffling results if you ever gave it data spanning more than one week.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found the answer myself:

```
SELECT sum(value), date, DAYNAME(date) as Day, case 
when TIME(date) >= '00:00' and TIME(date)< '07:00' then '00:00-07:00'
when TIME(date) >= '07:00' and TIME(date)< '11:00' then '07:00-11:00'
when TIME(date) >= '11:00' and TIME(date)< '13:00' then '11:00-13:00'
when TIME(date) >= '13:00' and TIME(date)< '19:00' then '13:00-19:00'
else '19:00-00:00' 
end as time_period
from data group by Day, time_period;
```